# c# using directive depth

Tags: c#

I'm trying to understand the c# using directive...Why does this work...

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
namespace BusinessRuleDemo
{
    class MyBusinessClass
    {
        [Required]
        public string SomeRequiredProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

but this does not?

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
namespace BusinessRuleDemo
{
    class MyBusinessClass
    {
        [DataAnnotations.Required]
        public string SomeRequiredProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The second results in a compile error "The type or namespace DataAnnotations cannot be found.  Are you missing are missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: try [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required]

Comment: I think his question is why can't he shortcut and continue to piggyback a namespace started by a using but not completed by it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

using directive makes it possible to use class names from the namespace you specified as its argument. Since DataAnnotations is not a class, but a namespace, it's not accessible in second case. You should either use fully qulified class names NS1.NS2.Class1, or start you program with using NS1.NS2; and then use Class1.

Comment: I'll accept this answer, but then I guess the compiler error should be "The type DataAnnotations cannot be found" and not "The type or namespace DataAnnotations cannot be found".  As you say, DataAnnotations is a namespace, so why is the compiler saying it cannot find the DataAnnotations namespace...

Comment: @Shawn de Wet: these are implementation details of C# compiler in fact. My answer is just the correct one. For compiler messages, I can't tell.

Comment: @Shawn, the compiler warning is correct. Namespaces are always fully-qualified in the C# compiler, so it's telling you that there is no such namespace as `DataAnnotations`. And there *is* no such namespace as `DataAnnotations`, only `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`.

Comment: @Shawn The compiler is being tricky here: It really *can't* find `DataAnnotations` as either a type or a namespace. What's going on is that it will search the current namespace as well as any namespaces specified by `using` for class name, but will *only* "search" the current namespace for other namespaces (since the actual namespace is the fully qualified one.) So the error is technically correct, once you realize what the search space for each classification is.

Comment: @JSBangs: you're great! Yes, for sure it just means global DataAnnotations namespace, not the nested one.

Answer (score 1):

Because you can either use [Fully Qualified Class Names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) or just use the ClassName and let .NET resolve it via `using` directive. There is no middle ground.

Class1 -

```
NameSpace1.NameSpace2.NameSpace3.Class1
```

can be accessed as

```
using NameSpace1.NameSpace2.NameSpace3;
...
... Class1.DoSomething();
...
```

or

```
...
NameSpace1.NameSpace2.NameSpace3.Class1.DoSomething();
...
```

but not like

```
using NameSpace1.NameSpace2;
...
NameSpace3.Class1.DoSomething();
...
```

In last case what compiler would actually be looking for is root namespace `NameSpace3` which clearly does not exist. It won't try to look for `System.NameSpace3` or `NameSpace1.NameSpace3` or `NameSpace1.NameSpace2.NameSpace3` etc etc.